# Creating a yes/no program with windows forms

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple program with Windows Forms. The idea is to keep asking the same question until user presses "no". What am I doing wrong here? The program kinda works, but it only asks the question two times and then it will exit the loop no matter what the answer is.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to continue?",
              "Huom!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    while (answer != DialogResult.No)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Do you want to continue?",
              "Huom!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: you never assign a *new* value to `answer`, so it will allways remain the value of your first answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the value of the variable `answer` within the loop like so:

`answer = MessageBox.Show...`

Also, this would go better in a do... while flow